# Function pointer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, function-pointers

Please explain me where I am wrong. I want to switch between several encoding utilities using pointer to function. I declare it like

```
int (*enc_routine)();
```

Later I switch coding utilities like

```
enc_routine = g723_24_encoder;
```

where utility by itself is something like

```
extern int g723_24_encoder(
    int sample,
    int in_coding,
    struct g72x_state *state_ptr);
```

Everything was cute and fine on Linux, but now I am on Visual Studio 2012 and it says:

> a value of type "int (*)(int sample, int in_coding, g72x_state *state_ptr)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int (*)()"

Thank you for help (if any)!

Comment: Are you compiling this as C++? The word “entity” is not usual in C vocabulary.

Comment: Should be C I suppose, since all my files in Project are .c not .cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the parameters for your function pointer.  You can't declare it to take no parameters and set it equal to a function that requires 3 parameters.  I'm shocked it worked on linux.

Comment: Yup, the first line needs to be `int (*enc_routine)(int, int, struct g72x_state*);`

Comment: “You can't declare it to take no parameters and set it equal to a function that requires 3 parameters” In C99, it is not declared to take no parameters, and you definitely can set it equal to a function that takes 3 parameters.